# Undesired output when ordering time-stamped data chronologically

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, time

This post is linked to a previous post of mine where I described having a problem with arranging time-stamped data in a chronological order. I sadly didn't have any conclusive answers so I tried something by myself with no luck. Hope I can use some help.

I'm working with the following time-stamped data:

```
> head(act.byHour_corr)
   hour                  date activity
1:    0 Activity on 6/20/2018       59
2:    1 Activity on 6/20/2018       74
3:    2 Activity on 6/20/2018     2683
4:    3 Activity on 6/20/2018     4341
5:    4 Activity on 6/20/2018     3676
6:    5 Activity on 6/20/2018     2143
```

Which as you can see isn't always chronologically ordered as the days in `act.byHour_corr` should be displayed consecutively:

```
> head(act.byHour_corr[287:293])
   hour                  date activity
1:   22  Activity on 7/1/2018      400
2:   23  Activity on 7/1/2018      201
3:    0 Activity on 7/10/2018      705
4:    1 Activity on 7/10/2018       47
5:    2 Activity on 7/10/2018      605
6:    3 Activity on 7/10/2018      257
```

To fix the issue I used the following code by trying to reformat the date and then use `order()`, however:

```
> act.byHour_corr$date <- as.Date(gsub('Activity on ', '', act.byHour_corr$date),
+                                 format = '%m/%d/%Y')
> act.byHour_corr$date <- act.byHour_corr[order(act.byHour_corr$date),]
Error in `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

If that helps I can provide my dataset below Any input is appreciated!:

```
> dput(act.byHour_corr)
structure(list(hour = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L), date = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L), class = "factor", .Label = c("Activity on 6/20/2018", 
"Activity on 6/21/2018", "Activity on 6/22/2018", "Activity on 6/23/2018", 
"Activity on 6/24/2018", "Activity on 6/25/2018", "Activity on 6/26/2018", 
"Activity on 6/27/2018", "Activity on 6/28/2018", "Activity on 6/29/2018", 
"Activity on 6/30/2018", "Activity on 7/1/2018", "Activity on 7/10/2018", 
"Activity on 7/11/2018", "Activity on 7/12/2018", "Activity on 7/13/2018", 
"Activity on 7/14/2018", "Activity on 7/15/2018", "Activity on 7/16/2018", 
"Activity on 7/17/2018", "Activity on 7/18/2018", "Activity on 7/19/2018", 
"Activity on 7/2/2018", "Activity on 7/20/2018", "Activity on 7/21/2018", 
"Activity on 7/22/2018", "Activity on 7/23/2018", "Activity on 7/24/2018", 
"Activity on 7/25/2018", "Activity on 7/26/2018", "Activity on 7/27/2018", 
"Activity on 7/28/2018", "Activity on 7/29/2018", "Activity on 7/3/2018", 
"Activity on 7/30/2018", "Activity on 7/31/2018", "Activity on 7/4/2018", 
"Activity on 7/5/2018", "Activity on 7/6/2018", "Activity on 7/7/2018", 
"Activity on 7/8/2018", "Activity on 7/9/2018")), activity = c(59L, 
74L, 2683L, 4341L, 3676L, 2143L, 3890L, 3887L, 1299L, 1492L, 
3449L, 2200L, 1563L, 4346L, 5329L, 3037L, 1462L, 668L, 383L, 
483L, 288L, 2765L, 3354L, 1783L, 241L, 301L, 261L, 3683L, 4356L, 
3736L, 2810L, 1841L, 3146L, 609L, 2998L, 4059L, 3690L, 3735L, 
1343L, 2087L, 894L, 341L, 240L, 2113L, 1684L, 3115L, 2890L, 138L, 
21L, 451L, 96L, 2918L, 2279L, 2282L, 4992L, 698L, 427L, 581L, 
1248L, 2184L, 1980L, 2364L, 568L, 2477L, 525L, 433L, 974L, 501L, 
760L, 67L, 297L, 1198L, 2L, 39L, 42L, 1182L, 1749L, 2144L, 3123L, 
1170L, 1641L, 1112L, 1526L, 1199L, 534L, 1481L, 2388L, 2756L, 
392L, 112L, 390L, 107L, 709L, 1122L, 1562L, 451L, 8L, 74L, 0L, 
158L, 780L, 3118L, 3292L, 2759L, 3121L, 2051L, 2387L, 900L, 627L, 
904L, 4283L, 3726L, 1273L, 977L, 326L, 163L, 1915L, 1073L, 1021L, 
545L, 36L, 22L, 3L, 55L, 124L, 22L, 4093L, 2867L, 3649L, 2550L, 
1590L, 636L, 2571L, 998L, 1066L, 2967L, 1211L, 51L, 1188L, 1413L, 
714L, 177L, 132L, 29L, 22L, 43L, 0L, 90L, 1094L, 1655L, 2643L, 
2108L, 2249L, 2453L, 2857L, 915L, 437L, 1142L, 2193L, 2993L, 
1139L, 1549L, 652L, 580L, 970L, 674L, 211L, 206L, 167L, 63L, 
1L, 786L, 617L, 1575L, 2237L, 1302L, 1149L, 2009L, 2234L, 1263L, 
1259L, 2017L, 1641L, 2683L, 1184L, 449L, 65L, 956L, 1538L, 1287L, 
593L, 362L, 594L, 1172L, 25L, 445L, 921L, 1812L, 2235L, 1153L, 
422L, 1084L, 2158L, 1610L, 845L, 1187L, 2528L, 2161L, 976L, 19L, 
747L, 570L, 576L, 19L, 304L, 2L, 301L, 7L, 399L, 494L, 723L, 
1088L, 771L, 85L, 1338L, 866L, 384L, 1356L, 2862L, 3805L, 2142L, 
1655L, 249L, 235L, 3L, 0L, 283L, 981L, 634L, 1370L, 9L, 137L, 
33L, 975L, 1690L, 1639L, 985L, 210L, 1266L, 2135L, 2080L, 1704L, 
2449L, 3133L, 1055L, 3222L, 1152L, 173L, 858L, 188L, 700L, 330L, 
905L, 1232L, 1006L, 5L, 21L, 520L, 1162L, 1771L, 2463L, 1403L, 
1353L, 1938L, 2388L, 4133L, 900L, 2660L, 3504L, 3946L, 1956L, 
818L, 604L, 937L, 373L, 48L, 400L, 201L, 705L, 47L, 605L, 257L, 
1359L, 41L, 1019L, 1426L, 2219L, 1179L, 1624L, 537L, 421L, 1747L, 
2941L, 2921L, 1046L, 283L, 476L, 218L, 59L, 389L, 657L, 1293L, 
24L, 455L, 6L, 1232L, 2264L, 1152L, 600L, 11L, 980L, 1519L, 2004L, 
1933L, 2161L, 1386L, 1883L, 2978L, 1385L, 104L, 1309L, 2L, 364L, 
550L, 0L, 1433L, 1634L, 27L, 860L, 1095L, 1102L, 132L, 582L, 
710L, 1368L, 2470L, 2944L, 1030L, 1286L, 387L, 2590L, 2449L, 
743L, 134L, 274L, 205L, 360L, 627L, 1357L, 591L, 216L, 143L, 
70L, 2L, 477L, 42L, 81L, 304L, 2827L, 2437L, 2002L, 688L, 935L, 
812L, 404L, 1098L, 1157L, 857L, 466L, 215L, 714L, 269L, 1223L, 
8L, 1L, 635L, 6L, 1797L, 1363L, 246L, 704L, 1089L, 943L, 2251L, 
813L, 2643L, 1657L, 18L, 1132L, 2884L, 1044L, 149L, 1146L, 68L, 
1227L, 1189L, 129L, 1291L, 7L, 9L, 1299L, 389L, 288L, 157L, 0L, 
324L, 248L, 915L, 795L, 598L, 733L, 308L, 2760L, 2874L, 1903L, 
499L, 73L, 31L, 1146L, 920L, 852L, 2L, 104L, 564L, 16L, 1903L, 
675L, 1859L, 720L, 1017L, 4L, 2114L, 2264L, 1152L, 935L, 1691L, 
1031L, 2568L, 2035L, 226L, 18L, 1716L, 249L, 717L, 635L, 919L, 
1436L, 16L, 17L, 1891L, 1175L, 74L, 435L, 377L, 718L, 619L, 439L, 
1373L, 2154L, 2481L, 763L, 2084L, 910L, 641L, 669L, 737L, 793L, 
1471L, 12L, 96L, 6L, 13L, 81L, 1227L, 1685L, 260L, 238L, 575L, 
930L, 330L, 1139L, 785L, 1110L, 1007L, 1770L, 2824L, 729L, 776L, 
602L, 550L, 1432L, 567L, 197L, 107L, 38L, 648L, 264L, 911L, 2239L, 
1063L, 9L, 1336L, 1235L, 628L, 1722L, 1028L, 1393L, 44L, 2110L, 
1719L, 666L, 127L, 885L, 788L, 1274L, 765L, 1094L, 38L, 876L, 
505L, 162L, 775L, 1567L, 896L, 1648L, 995L, 2574L, 1080L, 997L, 
1881L, 1375L, 1283L, 2156L, 2384L, 982L, 33L, 20L, 761L, 241L, 
696L, 133L, 915L, 514L, 14L, 59L, 1081L, 1266L, 359L, 1055L, 
280L, 123L, 2251L, 2302L, 1116L, 2750L, 764L, 1377L, 2776L, 970L, 
814L, 10L, 1364L, 1137L, 279L, 10L, 605L, 279L, 596L, 12L, 1443L, 
1463L, 1426L, 132L, 924L, 379L, 693L, 137L, 219L, 884L, 194L, 
450L, 1204L, 487L, 578L, 445L, 9L, 823L, 2L, 1212L, 12L, 200L, 
9L, 152L, 1062L, 1926L, 1156L, 1951L, 1735L, 753L, 570L, 362L, 
813L, 756L, 1403L, 308L, 1895L, 325L, 768L, 666L, 33L, 634L, 
1294L, 819L, 39L, 579L, 8L, 657L, 438L, 521L, 896L, 2560L, 1383L, 
819L, 1293L, 2257L, 476L, 1850L, 759L, 2482L, 1513L, 789L, 78L, 
329L, 43L, 50L, 1583L, 342L, 0L, 495L, 13L, 127L, 1415L, 1534L, 
939L, 2315L, 649L, 154L, 2838L, 1462L, 2255L, 1058L, 316L, 1825L, 
2391L, 324L, 185L, 813L, 997L, 830L, 407L, 796L, 624L, 1002L, 
6L, 86L, 1091L, 1951L, 8L, 1863L, 2555L, 799L, 749L, 2386L, 1893L, 
524L, 846L, 2263L, 2266L, 779L, 88L, 380L, 1495L, 1985L, 3L, 
1462L, 1450L, 1L, 19L, 967L, 1565L, 1066L, 9L, 99L, 4L, 1889L, 
1848L, 1924L, 471L, 1357L, 626L, 1465L, 1787L, 1437L, 115L, 322L, 
717L, 1639L, 990L, 1029L, 1112L, 372L, 8L, 256L, 1679L, 1209L, 
2246L, 2153L, 1762L, 1883L, 1551L, 998L, 728L, 1274L, 888L, 508L, 
2357L, 452L, 1167L, 2385L, 3280L, 320L, 1130L, 878L, 583L, 799L, 
4L, 61L, 394L, 1237L, 854L, 68L, 379L, 2910L, 3088L, 1011L, 840L, 
1024L, 2496L, 3079L, 2830L, 1841L, 1772L, 595L, 65L, 584L, 2110L, 
1966L, 473L, 21L, 847L, 293L, 881L, 840L, 1912L, 683L, 1362L, 
1276L, 3131L, 3110L, 1773L, 1077L, 1437L, 769L, 2311L, 1623L, 
562L, 42L, 1791L, 1318L, 1230L, 202L, 2630L, 623L, 918L, 48L, 
523L, 721L, 1624L, 1047L, 1783L, 313L, 1042L, 2211L, 2430L, 1770L, 
1610L, 2814L, 2460L, 1770L, 25L, 709L, 416L, 709L, 998L, 921L, 
89L, 1174L, 396L, 52L, 2261L, 1237L, 56L, 927L, 2491L, 3180L, 
352L, 81L, 2072L, 3207L, 2394L, 600L, 3280L, 1745L, 147L, 1L, 
1544L, 350L, 2198L, 1833L, 55L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
258L, 1242L, 75L, 1131L, 893L, 402L, 381L, 51L, 15L, 47L, 762L, 
777L, 479L, 2416L, 3639L, 1991L, 202L, 1054L, 917L, 1565L, 503L, 
61L, 44L, 2103L, 2212L, 352L, 1L, 666L, 351L, 1321L, 7L, 1010L, 
1222L, 1080L, 1643L, 1101L, 188L, 2793L, 1548L, 1811L, 1807L, 
51L, 788L, 1108L, 1157L, 1038L, 225L, 454L, 441L, 376L, 444L, 
5L, 501L, 579L, 1253L, 1600L, 1051L, 498L, 2217L, 2362L, 2425L, 
1220L, 2037L, 2684L, 799L, 471L, 139L, 545L, 1117L, 177L, 487L, 
1420L, 692L, 303L, 736L, 750L, 1386L, 926L, 30L, 862L, 1912L, 
2731L, 1123L, 1160L, 2892L, 1634L, 585L, 3473L, 2243L, 441L, 
399L, 1482L, 111L, 455L, 1315L, 691L, 1428L, 96L, 52L, 258L, 
1135L, 1727L, 448L, 2148L, 358L, 2180L, 1519L, 2634L, 828L, 1212L, 
1052L, 2851L, 902L, 171L, 236L, 3L, 727L, 1366L, 637L, 43L, 0L, 
1320L, 146L, 664L, 862L, 663L, 227L, 227L, 995L, 743L, 1793L, 
2421L, 1346L, 1874L, 2182L, 1333L, 1967L, 1023L, 297L, 340L, 
1469L, 10L, 213L, 805L)), row.names = c(NA, -1008L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002641ef0>)
```

Comment: If it is a data.table, you just need to `order`, `act.byHour_corr1 <- act.byHour_corr[order(date)]`

Comment: With `data.table`, the whole syntax can be `act.byHour_corr[, date := as.IDate(sub("Activity on ", "", date), "%m/%d/%Y")][order(date)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
act.byHour_corr %>%
  mutate(date = mdy(gsub("Activity on", "", date))) %>%
  arrange(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` methods as the object is a `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
act.byHour_corr <- act.byHour_corr[, date := as.IDate(sub("Activity on ", "", 
               date), "%m/%d/%Y")][order(date)]
```